# joomla 3.0 Call to undefined method JUtility::getToken()

Tags: joomla

I got this error while creating a joomla logout link. Here is my code please help

```
                        if($user->id){
                            $token = JUtility::getToken();
                            $linkout = JRoute::_("index.php?option=com_users&task=user.logout&".$token."=1");
```

}
and echo $linkout to anchor tag

Comment: Please elaborate your problem like what did you try to achieve by this.

Comment: on which page your tried this ? its inside joomla framework?

Answer (score 3):

JUtility::getToken() has been replaced by JSession::getFormToken(), thus code could be changed to:

```
&task=user.logout&<?php echo JSession::getFormToken(); ?>=1">
```

you may want to use this for further reference:
[joomla 3 and joomla platform 12.2 potential backward compatibility issues](http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3_and_Joomla_Platform_12.2)